# In Eclipse OMR, what does "OMR" stand for?

Tags: eclipse

I have been looking all over IBM and eclipse web sites and docs, but I can't find a definition for the OMR acronym anywhere. Can anyone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 5):

Today, *OMR* stands for *OMR*. In the past, *OMR* was an acronym for *Open Managed Runtime*.

Mark Stoodley, lead of Eclipse OMR:

> [we're no longer using "Open Managed Runtime". OMR is not an
>   acronym.](https://github.com/eclipse/omr/pull/158#issuecomment-233058261)

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick Google search, and I found [this website](https://www.eclipse.org/omr/starter/whatisomr.html) provided by Eclipse. I hope this helps!

Comment: Page doesn't contain any answer about abbreviation. Sometimes quick search is not enough.